# gRPC ASP.NET Core: what type to use instead of object?

Tags: asp.net-core, wcf, grpc

I have a class in my WCF service

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public object Value;
}
```

and I migrate the WCF to gRPC.NET ASP.NET Core service.

What class can I use in *.proto file to replace "object"?

Comment: Using WCF data contracts, the `object` would have also required a `KnownType` attribute on the class to let the serializer know what could potentially be in there. Maybe you could use this information to implement that as [`oneof`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof).

Comment: Yes, but it is little bit another: WCF reads some data from SQL Server database and a  table has sql_variant column. This object Value contains it value. I understand that sql_variant is a devil data type but it is existing database ;-) . I thought may be: string or bytes can be used?